# Changing the colour of Navigation Controller bottom toolBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, appdelegate

I am trying to change the colour of the bottom bar of my Navigation Controller.  I have managed to change the top NavBar in my appdelegate by adding

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.688 green:0.437 blue:0.794 alpha:1.0]];
```

I want to apply this to the bottom bar also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[UIToolbar appearance]` to set the appearance of UIToolbar

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but could escape this by setting a tag for my navigationBar in my storyboard. Then I could change the navigationBar's color like this:

let navigationBar = (self.view.viewWithTag(someNumber) as UINavigationBar)
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

This is not ideal unless you can guarantee that the number of subviews in your view is less than "someNumber". If you can though, then this should work.